# How to click file input programmatically in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have checked the Lightning Component documentation but I could not find the standard way to fire a click event for a file input by code.

The file input is kept hidden on page and I want to open its file browser window on click of a button.

Is there a standard to way to fire click event other than using the JS approach like `document.getElementById('file-input-id').click()`?

**Page Contents**

```
<input type="file" aura:id="file-input-id" id="file-input-id" style="display:none"  onchange="{!c.saveFile}"/>

<ui:button aura:id="button-id"  press="{!c.onButtonPress}"/>
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Why don't you call the method directly ?

Comment: Sorry, I will update the question. Initially I wanted to fire onchange event of a file input.

Comment: Instead of adding a `display:none;`, I would prefer to add a `position: absolute; left:-9999px;`.  And you should do `evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
          evt.initEvent('change', false, true);
          document.getElementById('file-input-id').dispatchEvent(evt)`.